# how to use decimal format to compare values?

Tags: java

Im getting two percent values-above percent and below percent as input from user and have to compare with  percent value which may be +12.05% or -12.05% and stored in database..I used decimal format and received error..

```
DecimalFormat newpercent= DecimalFormat.getPercentInstance(percent);
```

i receive error in getPercentInstance()..

whether the datatype im used is right?have to use any other datatype other than decimal format?

percent is string value in database..EX:

```
newpercent=percent
maxpercent=abovepercent
minpercent=belowpercent
```

further i will compare newpercent with maxpercent and minpercent in my code..

Comment: your question is not clear - what error you have received ??

Comment: "+12.05%" and "-12.05%" are strings and you want 12.05 and -12.05 as output? Can youcreate an example of input and output of the method you want to create?

Comment: ya it's stored as an string in DB.EX:

Comment: @manojashwin can you provide a sample string value of `percent` ?

Comment: receive error as:The method getPercentInstance(Locale) in the type NumberFormat is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: String value of percent will be either like +12.50% or -12.50%..in my code user will enter above and belowpercent values as like 12.50 and 12.00..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see what DecimalFormat has to do with comparing values at all. Just get the values as doubles or BigDecimals or whatever they are and compare them directly using the operators and methods provided for the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Though its not clear from your code what is `percent` but it seems that error is caused by that only
And checking its [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getPercentInstance%28java.util.Locale%29) its shows that `getPercentInstance` method takes `Locale` instance as argument

for example:
`DecimalFormat.getPercentInstance(Locale.ENGLISH)`